# Meaning of "也是吼"? Is it slang/colloquialism?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the meaning of "也是吼." It popped up in an instance without context. (It was its own sentence.)
I tried googling it and saw it popped up in books and on twitter so I was wondering if it's a slang term since I couldn't find it in a dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: Just treat that it is a typo or a variant of 哈/啊 on Internet

Answer (score 3):

It’s not a complete sentence. It’s something you’d say as a response in a conversation.

也是 means something like “indeed” in this scenario.

吼 is a word used at the end of sentences to express “emotion”. A close approximation would be “yeah...” in English.

Therefore, ”也是吼” means “yeah, right” or “yeah, indeed” when translated into English.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is a slang with complex backgroud.

The previous president Jiang has a funny accent(e.g. pronounce 好啊 as 吼啊), and he has made many characteristic speeches, among which the most famous one is "Answering the Hongkong journalist's questions".

Afterwards, the people who use the memes are called 膜法师. Their behaviours are called 膜蛤. Our reverend president is called 祂 in this circle.

You can dig up more like these:

-1s/蛤蛤/是吼的/图样图森破，上台拿衣服/谈笑风生, etc...

Comment: If 吼 is replacement of 好, what does "也是好" here mean? I don't think it make sense here .

Comment: Echoing tsh, I also think that 也是吼 is not related to 膜蛤 culture at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think you usually see "也是吼" from chat such as wechat, weibo etc (message apps). It's not an official use of Chinese. People like to use this to present "indeed"/ "yes, agreed".

It is equivalent to "也是哦"，“也是哈”， “也是啊”.

- "也是" means “indeed“， ”agreed“.
- ”吼“ / ”啊“ / ”哈“ means an emotion like - :o, xD, ;D

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just Taiwan accent?

也是吼 = 也是哦